# adding Images(srcs) from web to ListView

Tags: java, android

I've got `ArrayList` of Image src_s from web (Parsed with `JSoup`) , I want to add this images into `ImageViews` in `ListView`.

Is it possible to do with `Picasa` library ?

Or there is more easier way to do this ?

Comment: picaso and other library like that is the simplest way that i know

Answer (score 0):

Use [Universal Image loader Library](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
create a custom adapter for your listview and in the 
getview method of adapter use this:

```
imageUrl = yourArrayList.get(position);
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, optionsOfImageLoader);
```